# Predict multiple values as model result in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

I have created a model using scikit learn algorithm.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10,random_state=seed)
rf.fit(X_train,Y_train)

shift_id=2099.0
user_id=1402.0
status=['S']
shift_organisation_id=15.0
shift_department_id=20.0
open_positions=71.0
city=['taunton']
role_id=3.0
specialty_id=16.0
years_of_experience=10.0
nurse_zip=2780.0
shifts_zip=2021.0

status = status_encoder.transform(status)
city = city_encoder.transform(city)

X = np.array([shift_id, user_id, status, shift_organisation_id, shift_department_id, open_positions, city, role_id, specialty_id, years_of_experience, nurse_zip, shifts_zip])
location_id = rf.predict(X.reshape(1,-1))
print(location_id)
```

which gives result like this

> [25]

What I understand is `25` is the best prediction value for this model. But I want to get top best 3 values as a result. How can I get it?

In that case prediction result would be like

> [23,45,25]

Comment: What are the shapes of the input data?

Comment: @yatu:  inpute data is numpy array. I

Answer (score 1):

You can you `predict_proba` method to return class probabilities and get top 3 values from it [ref](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10,random_state=seed)
rf.fit(X_train,Y_train)

shift_id=2099.0
user_id=1402.0
status=['S']
shift_organisation_id=15.0
shift_department_id=20.0
open_positions=71.0
city=['taunton']
role_id=3.0
specialty_id=16.0
years_of_experience=10.0
nurse_zip=2780.0
shifts_zip=2021.0

status = status_encoder.transform(status)
city = city_encoder.transform(city)

X = np.array([shift_id, user_id, status, shift_organisation_id, shift_department_id, open_positions, city, role_id, specialty_id, years_of_experience, nurse_zip, shifts_zip])
location_id = rf.predict_proba(X.reshape(1,-1))
print(location_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) method for that, which returns the prediction of the class probabilities.

Lets check on an example using the [iris dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html):

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target
# train/test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, random_state=10)
rf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

If you now call the [`predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict) method, as expected you get the highest probability class:

```
rf.predict(X_test)
# array([1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, ...
```

However calling [`predict_proba`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)you will get the corresponding probabilities:

```
rf.predict_proba(X_test)

array([[0.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.11      , 0.1       , 0.79      ],
       [0.        , 0.7       , 0.3       ],
       [0.5       , 0.4       , 0.1       ],
       [0.        , 0.3       , 0.7       ],
       [0.5       , 0.2       , 0.3       ],
       [0.4       , 0.        , 0.6       ],
       ...
```

In order to get the highest `k` probabilities you could use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and index the corresponding probabilities `rf.classes_`:

```
k = 2
rf.classes_[rf.predict_proba(X_test).argsort()[:,-k:]]

array([[2, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       ...
```

In the above can be improved using [`argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) as wer'e only interested in the top `k` probabilities:

```
rf.classes_[rf.predict_proba(X_test).argpartition(range(k))[:,-k:]]
```